# How to implement batch operations with storage

Tags: azure, powershell

We use Azure CLI to write a script to delete a storage account container's content and upload the contents of a directory to container

```
az storage blob delete-batch --account-name $ACCOUNT_NAME --source $web
az storage blob upload-batch --account-name $ACCOUNT_NAME -s $SOURCE_PATH -d $web
```

Now, we want to host the script on Azure. According to our search, we cannot directly host Azure CLI script on Azure and we must migrate the script to powershell. But we cannot find similar powershell commands. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Current version of Azure PowerShell at the time of writing this answer is 3.1 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/?view=azps-3.1.0#storage) and unfortunately batch operations on blobs is not supported there.

Thus using Azure PowerShell Cmdlets is not possible as of version 3.1 to perform batch operations on blobs.

One option for you is to use `Azure Storage Blobs Batch client library for .NET`. You can write PowerShell script that makes use of this library to perform batch operations on blobs. You can find more information and code samples here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs.Batch/README.md.

Other option would be to consume REST API. Again, you can write PowerShell script that makes the HTTP requests to perform batch operations against your storage account. You can find more information about the REST API here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-batch.

P.S: I would've included the code but unfortunately my knowledge in PowerShell is very limited :).